# Mac Lion Apache can't view files in document root

Tags: macos, apache, osx-lion

Apache is running, localhost is working, if I put an index.html that works as well.  However I can't access any folders (my websites) within the document root, which is /Users/Me/Sites

I get a forbidden error when I try to access these.

What's going wrong?

Comment: did you try to use the sudo command?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the permissions of your home folder and your sites directory to make sure that they allow Apache access.

You could check the permissions, or just run (in a Terminal)

- chmod o+x $HOME
- chmod -R o+rX $HOME/Sites